# magento: change label text in back end

Tags: magento

I have managed to change "state/province" in the front end of the checkout and registration to "county". How can also I change this in the back end on pages "manage customers" and "customer information >> addresses"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'll specify a custom locale for the admin store, and you'll do it in a custom module. Whereas all of the configuration is compiled as one DOM structure though you can add this to app/etc/local.xml:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <locale>custom</locale>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

Then create this file:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/locale/[e.g. en_US]/translate.csv
```

and in that file, you'll have one entry:

```
"State/Province","County"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was something like that. It's a lot of work just to change one word, but i suppose there's a reason for it. I think my client will just have to live with it. Magento is a great system; but from a newcomer's perspective you often are left wondering why certain things aren't a bit more simple.